# Is there not equal ( !== ) statement in SCSS?

Tags: if-statement, sass

How to add additional style if the value is passed? Or is there any way to do it?

```
@mixin link($color, $color-hover:false){
 color: $color;
 @if $color-hover !== false {
  &:hover { color: $color-hover; }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Is `!=` not working for you? I suppose you are trying with `!==`. i.e. a Double '=' instead of a single '=' prefixed with '!'. For SCSS, equality operators (==, !=) are supported for all types.

Comment: oh -_-, I overthought about it. Thnx!

Comment: so if I accidentally do `=` in an if statement is that assigning? or are `=` and `==` equivalent?